# How to change blogger templete language from indonesian to english?

Tags: blogger

I am using Sang Seo blogger template by Kang Mousir on my blog http://niyogbatori.blogspot.com But this template has like button name as "Suka" and Home button as "Beranda" and comment as "Koment" any many indonesian word.. How to change language of blogger template to English ?? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your language is "en-US" by following this link : http://www.the-area51.com/2013/02/declare-language-blogger-template.html

Comment: Link only is not good as link may expire and answer may become useless. Please add a basic form of the answer, and use the link as an additional reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the blog's Language under Settings | Language and formatting.
[image]